Hot to set PDF/UA identifier with PDFBOX
The PAC 2024 Validation Tool, give me that error.
 Metadata: PDF/UA identifier is missing

I use

org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.2

How can I set the identifier to a PDDocument?

// file from https://taggedpdf.com/xmp/pdfUA-ID.xmp
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("pdfUA-ID.xmp")))
{
    XMPMetadata xmp = XMPMetadata.load(is);
    xmp.addDublinCoreSchema();
    XMPSchemaDublinCore dc = xmp.getDublinCoreSchema();
    dc.setTitle("Title");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    xmp.save(baos);
    PDMetadata meta = new PDMetadata(doc, new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setMetadata(meta);
}

this one uses jempbox because xmpbox fails with that schema
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.17</version>
</dependency>


This solution fixes the PDF/UA Identify Issue, but creates a new one. "Title in XMP Metadata" missed.

Next attempt. I'm now loading the file locally, I got http 403 errors, maybe they don't that people download something twice.

If he creates thousands of files for a mailing where only the address changes, then there is no need to check everyone of them. He'll check one manually, and if that one is OK then my solution is what's needed.
